# How to pass redux props and navigation parameters together?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-native-navigation

I have successfully passed react native navigation parameters as follows:

```
PageOne = ({ navigation, route }) => {
const { itemId, otherParam } = route.params;
...
}
```

And I have done passing redux props to use redux actions as follows:

```
PageTwo = (props) => {

}
```

How can I put the parameters and the props together into a component?

Your help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```html
Page = (props) => {
const { navigation, route } = props
const { itemId, otherParam } = route.params;
...
}
```

Comment: It worked like a cham! You saved a day for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can combine them like:

```
PageOne = ({ navigation, route, reduxParam1,reduxParam2 }) => {
const { itemId, otherParam } = route.params;
}
```

or you can use like this too

```
PageOne = (props) => {
const { itemId, otherParam } = props.route.params;
}
```